# How to map or copy a wordpress site to a subfolder in an existing site's route?

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have a Wordpress blog (blog.xxx.com). I have a nuxt personal website yyy.com which is hosted on aws.

Now I wish to map or migrate the Wordpress blog (blog.xxx.com) to my personal site (yyy.com/blog).

How can we achieve this? yyy.com should show my personal site and yyy.com/blog should take you to my blog.

Can I configure this in Wordpress or what else can I do to achieve this?

I tried mapping it to a new domain, but I’m not sure how to map to a particular route and get it to work when I visit (yyy.com/blog/{blog-name}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set up a WP site in a subfolder of your main website. I don't recommend doing it manually, too much can go wrong. Use a [plugin such as Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) - it's so simple to use:

1. Install it on the **site to copy** and build a package - this packages your entire website into a single zip file
2. Copy this ZIP file and installer.php to the the hosting **new location** on your hosting (e.g. `yyy.com/blog`)
3. Create a new **empty database**
4. Run the **installer wizard** and make sure the URL in the new settings is `https://www.yyy.com/blog`

**That's it!**

You can have the entire site set up & running perfectly in just minutes! it will even set up `.htaccess` correctly.

No more setting up the database, changing urls in the database, 404 errors, broken links, broken images, etc. Moving a Wordpress site manually can be tricky and you can waste hours trying to fix the issues. Even agencies use a plugin to avoid the problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to move your WordPress installation from `blog.xxx.com` to `yyy.com/blog`, right?
There is an official guide for this provided by WordPress: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

After you have changed the `siteurl` and `home` fields in table `wp_options` of your database to `yyy.com/blog`, you can use a plugin like **Better Search Replace** (https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) that scans your WordPress database and replaces every URL of posts etc. with the new URL of your blog.

In addition, in case of an Apache webserver you need to take care of the `.htaccess` file and change the `RewriteBase` to `/blog` (assuming that it was `/` before).

Some special plugins (for caching etc.) need some special treatment, but often clearing the cache solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well despite Johannes is perfectly clear for me, i'll try to simplify.

1. Clone WordPress files from blog.xxx.com to yyy.com/blog directory. (not sure how your server is configured, but probably you'll be able to access it.)
2. Clone Database to new server.
3. Run sql replace queries:

```sql
    UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://blog.xxx.com', 'https://yyy.com/blog') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
    
    UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'https://blog.xxx.com','https://yyy.com/blog');
    
    UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://blog.xxx.com', 'https://yyy.com/blog');
    
    UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'https://blog.xxx.com','https://yyy.com/blog');
```

4. update your wp-config.php to match your new database.
5. login to yyy.com/blog/wp-admin
6. go to settings and update your permalinks