# How to replace domain name in an existing Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, dns

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="http://amac-china.com.cn/cft/xmlrpc.php">

<title>彩辉纺织 – 一流管理、一流技术、一流服务，造一流的品质</title>
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//amac-china.com.cn">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s.w.org">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="彩辉纺织 » Feed" href="http://amac-china.com.cn/cft/feed/">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="彩辉纺织 » 评论Feed" href="http://amac-china.com.cn/cft/comments/feed/">
        
        </script><script src="http://amac-china.com.cn/cft/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.14" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
        
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" id="sydney-font-awesome-css" href="http://amac-china.com.cn/cft/wp-content/themes/sydney/fonts/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.9.14" type="text/css" media="all">
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='sydney-ie9-css'  href='http://amac-china.com.cn/cft/wp-content/themes/sydney/css/ie9.css?ver=4.9.14' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://amac-china.com.cn/cft/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script></head>
```

how to replace "amac-china.com.cn" with "leavenotrace.cn"?
where is setting in wordpress?

Comment: There is no setting... that’s the location of the website and is crucial for the operation of WP, so there’s a lot more to it than just switching a domain name - it’s used in the WP settings, every url in the database, possibly hardcoded in the theme if it’s custom. When you say you want to replace the domain name, I assume you are trying to migrate the site to a new domain?

Comment: This "amac-china.com.cn" is no longer valid and I need a new domain name, but I don’t know how to replace it. So that I cannot open my webpage:leavenotrace.cn

Comment: how to migrate the site:amac-china.com.cn  to a new domain: leavenotrace.cn?

Comment: Take a look at [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276336/how-to-migrate-or-map-a-wordpress-site-to-an-existing-sites-route/62399760#62399760) for how to migrate to a new domain (it’s about moving to a sub domain but it’s the same process). If you’re not moving to a new hosting platform, try the “database only” option to set up a new database and then point to the new database in your wp-config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot can go wrong when you’re trying to change a fundamental setting like the domain. If you are not moving the files, I think the easiest way for you might be to create a new database with the new domain and then change the existing website to use this simply by updating the database settings in wp-config.php

Then use a plugin to do the hard work of correctly updating all references to the old domain. There might be another plugin to do this but I’m most familiar with the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

1. Install the plugin on the existing website and build a new package but *make sure you choose the “database only” option*!
2. Download this ZIP file and installer.php to your hosting
3. Create a new **empty database**
4. Run the **installer wizard**, enter your new database details and make sure the URL in the new settings is your new domain.

Now you just need to update the database details in wp-config.php so your website will use the new database.

This will update the database and system settings which should be everything. Just in case there are hardcoded references to the old domain, do a text search on your files. In particular, check your `.htaccess` for any hardcoded redirects.

*There are ways of updating the URLs directly in the existing database, but I prefer this option because it sets up the new database without affecting the existing one - so if anything goes wrong, you can switch back easily and try again.*

Comment: Don’t forget to backup everything first... just the on the safe side!

Answer (score 1):

Export the .sql file, then use your favorite code editor to open the exported .sql file and search for and replace the old domain name with the new domain name. Then directly delete all data tables in the site database, and then import it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

another way, execute SQL in Database:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://old.com', 'http://new.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://old.com','http://www.newurl');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://old.com', 'http://new.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://old.com','http://new.com');
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://old.com', 'http://new.com');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE (comment_content, 'http://old.com', 'http://new.com');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_author_url = REPLACE (comment_author_url, 'http://old.com','http://new.com');
```

Comment: **A word of warning to other users**: Only do this if you are *100% sure* what you are doing, otherwise you could break your site beyond repair. This can work if there are no plugins\custom code creating their own tables and tables use the default prefix, but every installation can differ. *Making changes directly in the database is generally discouraged* as it's all too easy to break the entire site. I'm very familiar with SQL (I even worked on Oracle database query optimisation in the past) and even I wouldn't directly update any system's database unless absolutely unavoidable!

Comment: Yes, It is risky. Thanks.