# Old domain is used for media WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with Wordpress, I changed my domain, but all media use the old domain.
For example :

I access my site with [www.newdomain.fr](http://www.newdomain.fr)
but in source code all src="" or media are with [www.olddomaine.fr/wp-content/..](http://www.olddomaine.fr/wp-content/..).

How can I change this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace domain name in an existing Wordpress site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717290/how-to-replace-domain-name-in-an-existing-wordpress-site)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options this can come from.

You probably have to migrate the whole database and it's serialized strings to the new domain name - for instance take a look at this Plugin [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) and replace the old domain name with the new one in your DB (don't forget to backup everything before you to this), this plugin should also handle the serialized data

If this doesn't resolve your issue you should take a look at your template code and even the css, there could be hard coded urls you have to replace (this should be considered as a bad practice and if this is the case you should build the template more dynamically)