# Domain gets rerouted to old server on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean

I create a clone of an existing site. The pointed a new domain to this droplet. Went in and changed wp-config.php, .htaccess, function.php. When I try to visit the new domain, it is still routing to the old server. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to migrate or map a wordpress site to an existing site's route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276336/how-to-migrate-or-map-a-wordpress-site-to-an-existing-sites-route)

Comment: There’s a lot more to  migrating a Wordpress installation than changing those files - everything on the Wordpress settings and database also use the domain. The link above shows you what to do (that question is for a subdomain but it’s exactly the same process)

Comment: Thanks. Let me given this a try and see.