# I want to publish my wordpress website (blog.domain.com) under my nginx website (domain.com) as domain.com/blog

Tags: wordpress, nginx, kubernetes

I want to publish my wordpress website (blog.domain.com) under my nginx website (domain.com)  as domain.com/blog.

```
blog.domain.com --> wordpress website on GCP 
domain.com --> have nginx web server on GCP
```

I want my website to work under domain.com/blog

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to migrate or map a wordpress site to an existing site's route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276336/how-to-migrate-or-map-a-wordpress-site-to-an-existing-sites-route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this configuration:

```
server {
server_name yourdomain.com;
}
server {
server_name ~(.*)\.yourdomain\.com$;
set $someword $1 ;
return 301 https://yourdomain.com/$someword;
}
```

Then you will be redirected as you mentioned, you can see more detailed information from [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)