# unable to login wordpress locally

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am a beginner in WordPress and know very little about it.
I have a SQL database and a Wordpress theme, which I have installed by adding the theme folder into htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes of the XAMPP folder and I have loaded SQL Database through phpMyAdmin.

I have done everything and entered database connection details successfully.
But while login I am facing an issue.

This is my wp-login.php

[image]

But when I click on login with my local Wordpress details (doesn't matter I enter them right or wrong), I get redirected to the login of my production version, which I don't want.

[image]

I want to just use that production version on my XAMPP localhost.

How can I do this? is there something I have done wrong? What's redirecting it to my production site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to migrate or map a wordpress site to an existing site's route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276336/how-to-migrate-or-map-a-wordpress-site-to-an-existing-sites-route) (It is about a sub-folder, but the same process in all the answers apply)

Comment: "*What's redirecting it to my production site?*" - probably your entire site. Did you just make a direct copy of the production site and put it onto the localhost? That doesn't work with WP - the database, config files (and possibly even theme files if they are badly developed) all have the complete URL to the site it was installed on. See the question above for how to fix the problem.

Comment: I just have the WordPress theme and the database. I don't have any installer.php or like that. I just want to host that theme over my localhost(hosted through xampp) with database hosted on xampp, which I am unable to do.

Comment: You use the Duplicator plugin to create the installer.php - just install Duplicator on the site to copy and use it to create a full install copy of the site with all the changes made for you, including the urls. All the steps are described in that answer. You can also manually change all the references in the database, the files etc, that the other answers describe, but that usually takes a lot longer and is *much* more prone to errors - one of the most common questions about WP here is when copying a site goes wrong!

Comment: First thing.. I don't have credentials of production site. I just have theme and the db. Second thing.. I want it on localhost.. third thing.. I am unable to even see my Wordpress dashboard. I know, I have to manually change configuration of Wordpress. help me finding that issue.

Comment: You need to change the database and files before you can log in, that is described in the other answers in that question.,There are also more answers to this question on Stack Overflow if you do a search because it has been asked in various forms before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour occurs when the `siteurl` and `home` fields in your options database table are still pointing to the live site.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Override the values using constants in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/wordpress');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/wordpress');
```

2. Update the values in the database. Since you're already using phpMyAdmin you should be able to use that to browse your database and modify values in the options table. The default table prefix is "wp_" so either look for the "wp_options" table, or if you use another prefix it will be "[prefix]options". Look for the values `site_url` and `home` (normally found among the first 30 rows or so depending how old the site is) and update them to match your local environment: 'http://localhost/wordpress'.