# Subdomain keeps redirecting to main site and won't change

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, multisite

I had an old wordpress multisite that I wanted to move to a subdomain.
I created a new subdomain, moved the multisite's files to its new folder, and changed all the tables' links.
I also edited the wp-config file and set the subdomain parameter to true.

However, when I try to access the subdomain it always redirects to the main site.

I tried looking for any redirect codes in the .htaccess file and removed them, but nothing changed.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm currently stuck.

Here is the .htaccess file (the original file)

```
    #WFIPBLOCKS - Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data.
Order Deny,Allow
#Start of blocking code for IP range: 195.154.128.0 - 195.154.255.255
Deny from 195.154.128.0/17
#End of blocking code for IP range: 195.154.128.0 - 195.154.255.255
#Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data - WFIPBLOCKS
#WFCACHECODE - Do not remove this line. Disable Web Caching in Wordfence to remove this data.
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/html .html_gzip
    AddEncoding gzip .html_gzip
    AddType text/xml .xml_gzip
    AddEncoding gzip .xml_gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.html_gzip$ no-gzip
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.xml_gzip$ no-gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie"
</IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Prevents garbled chars in cached files if there is no default charset.
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    #Cache rules:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=WRDFNC_HTTPS:_https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=WRDFNC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:\d+=\d+)?$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (?:\/|\.html)$ [NC]
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|wf_logout|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle|wpmp_switcher) [NC]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)(.*)$
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/wfcache/%{HTTP_HOST}_%1/%2~%3~%4~%5~%6_wfcache%{ENV:WRDFNC_HTTPS}.html%{ENV:WRDFNC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule \/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)\/*([^\/]*)(.*)$ "/wp-content/wfcache/%{HTTP_HOST}_$1/$2~$3~$4~$5~$6_wfcache%{ENV:WRDFNC_HTTPS}.html%{ENV:WRDFNC_ENC}" [L]
    </IfModule>
    #Do not remove this line. Disable Web caching in Wordfence to remove this data - WFCACHECODE
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent


# WP Super Simple Speed by WP-Superformance.com Starts

# Hotlink Protection Start

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?humsc.net/nada [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

# GZIP Compression Start

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

# Leverage Browser Caching Start

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

# Caching of common files Start

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|swf|js|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|txt|html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Enable Keepalive Start

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

# Use UTF-8 encoding Start

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Enable Vary: Accept-Encoding Start

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# WP Super Simple Speed by WP-Superformance.com Ends



# WP Super Simple Speed by WP-Superformance.com Starts

# Hotlink Protection Start

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?humsc.net/naseem [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

# GZIP Compression Start

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>

# Leverage Browser Caching Start

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>

# Caching of common files Start

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|swf|js|css|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|txt|html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Enable Keepalive Start

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>

# Use UTF-8 encoding Start

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Enable Vary: Accept-Encoding Start

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# WP Super Simple Speed by WP-Superformance.com Ends


# BEGIN EWWWIO

# END EWWWIO
```

Comment: get into phpmyadmin and look at your wp_options table at the records for "siteurl" and "home".  Update if needed.

Comment: Already did. But I fear I might have missing tables, what should I do in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map or copy a wordpress site to a subfolder in an existing site's route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276336/how-to-map-or-copy-a-wordpress-site-to-a-subfolder-in-an-existing-sites-route) - this question is about moving to a subfolder instead of subdomain, but the process of moving a WP site from one location to another is identical, no matter what it is moving to or from.

Comment: Thank you @fluffykitten. But sadly, it doesn't. Once I added my new website to my root domain, I've been unable to access my old website from the front end to run any plugins, since it always redirects me to the new website (which is now on the root domain). However, I did confirm (manually) many times that all mentions of the url have been changed but to no avail.

Comment: Rather than wasting more time trying to find the problem, my suggestion is to simply reinstall the new website using the Duplicator plugin (or another similar plugin) - You won't lose anything because you haven't been able to access the site to make any changes, and you'll have the new site up and running in a few minutes - quite literally! If it was me, that's what I would do anyway - I've copied dozens of sites from development to production environments like this and never an issue!

Comment: I've done that and it worked. After losing hope in foguring out what's wrong I simply re did everything and copied the websites. Thank you so much for your help and support