# Wordpress subpages give 404 in windows subdirectory installation

Tags: wordpress, web-config, http-status-code-404, windows-server

I am migrating a site from a linux server to a windows server. The site has a wordpress installation in a **/blog** subfolder. All the pages of the wordpress site give a 404, except for the homepage.

I tried adding the following to the web.config, which is in the root of the domain:

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="WordPress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

As this had worked for previous windows wordpress installations, but those previous installations were in the root of the domain, not in a subdirectory.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map or copy a wordpress site to a subfolder in an existing site's route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62276336/how-to-map-or-copy-a-wordpress-site-to-a-subfolder-in-an-existing-sites-route) This question is for a subfolder, but the process is exactly the same for a subdomain - there might be something in those answers to help?

Comment: No, it does not help. The wp site was always in the /blog subfolder. The only thing changing is that the entire domain is moving from a linux server to a windows server. Therefore htaccess is no longer used and I have to use web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, I just needed to put the web.config file, with the above snippet in the subfolder where my wp installation was AND remove it from the root of the domain. I had previously done the former without the latter only.